# Changing vCenter FQDN will affect to connect esxi servers?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm planning to change the fqdn (e.g vcenter.abc.com to vcenter.def.com) of vcenter server that connected with three ESXi servers. I want to know if I will change the fqdn with another DNS server in vCenter, the connection between vCenter and ESXi will be affected or not.

Comment: This might be helpfull - https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2019/08/changing-your-vcenter-servers-fqdn.html

Comment: @batistuta09 thank for that. but that is how to instructions.

Comment: Based on instruction: the connection will be affected. ESXi hosts should be removed and readded after FQDN change